# What does derived union implies in this diagram

Tags: uml

[image]
The above diagram is taken from the UML Specification 2.5 Chapter 7 page 21.

For this diagram what does union mean when there is an association from element to it self. I have searched for the definition of union and I found:
"Property is a derived union of its subsets."
Could anybody explains what does this means?

The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16614366/uml-metamodel-derived-derived-union-and-subsetting) does not really address this problem nor the answer given do explain the property union

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UML metamodel: derived, derived union and subsetting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16614366/uml-metamodel-derived-derived-union-and-subsetting)

Answer (score 4):

Think of the sentence in mathematical terms; imagine that an `Element` has a set (mathematical set) of `owner`s, and a set of `ownedElement`. Now if you look closely at the image you posted you see that already there are some association derivations.

[image]

If we now look only at the red one, you see that the association between `Element` and `Comment` subsets the one between `Element` and `Element` itself. Thus if you were to query all `owner`s of a particular `Element`, you will receive the *union* of all the subsets.

The same rule applies for other elements, such as the relationsips (in blue), where the DirectedRelationship subsets Relationship, but if you query directly on the relationship you will received the union of it all.

And of course if you look at other diagrams in the UML infrastructure you will see that there are many more associations that subset each other.